# How to query with hard-coded month and current year

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an Access table that includes a column called ClaimDate. I have a report that shows various things, and the user form for the report asks them to enter the date range for the dataset they wish to display on the report. However, at the bottom of the report I have a running tally for the year. It all works just fine, but I am hardcoding the dates at the bottom like such;

```
 WHERE tbl_CSRQA.CustomerServiceRep=[forms]![frm_CSRErrorTracking]![CSRNameCB] AND tbl_CSRQA.ClaimDate Between #7/1/2019# And #7/31/2019#
```

What I would like to do is keep the hardcoding for the month/day, but change the year to just the current year. That way I don't have to go back and update all these queries when 2020 hits.

I know I can use the Year(Date()) function to get the current year, but I am having troubles integrating that into my query. I assumed it would be something like this;

```
  WHERE tbl_CSRQA.CustomerServiceRep=[forms]![frm_CSRErrorTracking]![CSRNameCB] AND tbl_CSRQA.ClaimDate Between #7/1# & Year(Date()) And #7/31# & Year(Date())
```

However that just gives me an error.

Here is the full query;

```
 SELECT tbl_CSRQA.ClaimantAdded, tbl_CSRQA.DocsPhoneCall, tbl_CSRQA.InsdDriverVehInfo, tbl_CSRQA.LossInfo, tbl_CSRQA.TemplateCalNotes, tbl_CSRQA.EmailtoLiab, tbl_CSRQA.ReserveScreen, tbl_CSRQA.InsNamePhone, tbl_CSRQA.Clerical, tbl_CSRQA.AdditionalSteps AS [Total Claim Errors Jul]

 FROM tbl_CSRQA IN '\\blcorp\shares\Claims\Liability Claims\Correspondence\CAST Database\Protective Insurance CAST Database Tables.accdb'

 WHERE tbl_CSRQA.CustomerServiceRep=[forms]![frm_CSRErrorTracking]![CSRNameCB] AND tbl_CSRQA.ClaimDate Between #7/1/2019# And #7/31/2019# AND 
 (tbl_CSRQA.ClaimantAdded="No" OR 
 tbl_CSRQA.DocsPhoneCall="No" OR 
 tbl_CSRQA.InsdDriverVehInfo="No" OR 
 tbl_CSRQA.LossInfo="No" OR 
 tbl_CSRQA.TemplateCalNotes="No" OR 
 tbl_CSRQA.EmailtoLiab="No" OR 
 tbl_CSRQA.ReserveScreen="No" OR 
 tbl_CSRQA.InsNamePhone="No" OR
 tbl_CSRQA.Clerical="No" OR
 tbl_CSRQA.AdditionalSteps="No");
```

All I really need to do is just update the query so that the hardcoded dates just look for the current year, instead of me having to input "2019" or "2020".

Comment: Try `DateSerial(Year(Date()),7,31)`.

Comment: This worked perfect. Thank you for the quick reply and easy answer. Much appreciated.